# solr update with json causes error

Tags: json, solr

I am following a tutorial from [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON). The example file books.json gets successfully synced with solr. The file file books.json looks something like this

```
[
  {
    "id" : "978-0641723445",
    "cat" : ["book","hardcover"],
    "name" : "The Lightning Thief",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 12.50,
    "pages_i" : 384
  }
]
```

Similar to the cat field i have a field tags. I have edited the schema.xml file to

```
<field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

On running the command curl `'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @myJson.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'`
, i get an error

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":16},"error":{"msg":"ERROR: [doc=book_name] unknown field 'tags'","code":400}}
```

Can someone suggest me where to check and rectify the error?

Comment: Have you restarted Solr or reloaded the core (in the admin interface) after changing `schema.xml`?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes i reloaded the core after changing schema.xml

Comment: Do you see the field if you go to Admin/(select collection)/ and then `SchemaBrowser` or `Analysis` or `files/schema.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your field placed in the **fields** sections together with other fields? Sometimes, people put it in an incorrect location of the schema.xml and it is just not found. AdminUI will show you if the field is known.

In Solr 4.8, the **fields** and **types** sections have been deprecated, so this issue should go away.